# How to find out if a date is after the end of a period

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, datetime, period

In this dataset, I want to find out (element-wise) whether `date` happens after the end of the period given in `week`.

```py
    import pandas as pd
    df = pd.DataFrame({
    "week": pd.period_range('2018-03-01', '2018-05-01', freq='W'),
    "date": pd.date_range('2018-04-09', periods=10, freq='D')
    })
```

Expected Output:

```
                    week       date    out
0  2018-02-26/2018-03-04 2018-04-09  True
1  2018-03-05/2018-03-11 2018-04-10  True
2  2018-03-12/2018-03-18 2018-04-11  True
3  2018-03-19/2018-03-25 2018-04-12  True
4  2018-03-26/2018-04-01 2018-04-13  True
5  2018-04-02/2018-04-08 2018-04-14   True
6  2018-04-09/2018-04-15 2018-04-15   False
7  2018-04-16/2018-04-22 2018-04-16   False
8  2018-04-23/2018-04-29 2018-04-17   False
9  2018-04-30/2018-05-06 2018-04-18   False
```

I tried [end_time](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Period.start_time.html?highlight=start_time#pandas.Period.start_time), but this does not work with a Series of Periods.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`Series.to_timestamp`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.to_timestamp.html) with `.dt` for not working with `DatetimeIndex` and parameter `how='e'`:

```
df['out'] = df['week'].dt.to_timestamp(how='e') < df['date']
print (df)
                    week       date    out
0  2018-02-26/2018-03-04 2018-04-09   True
1  2018-03-05/2018-03-11 2018-04-10   True
2  2018-03-12/2018-03-18 2018-04-11   True
3  2018-03-19/2018-03-25 2018-04-12   True
4  2018-03-26/2018-04-01 2018-04-13   True
5  2018-04-02/2018-04-08 2018-04-14   True
6  2018-04-09/2018-04-15 2018-04-15  False
7  2018-04-16/2018-04-22 2018-04-16  False
8  2018-04-23/2018-04-29 2018-04-17  False
9  2018-04-30/2018-05-06 2018-04-18  False
```